# (discord.js v13) If channel exists

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm making a ticketing system with buttons. I trying to if user opened a ticket, user can't open a new ticket. Im tried some code:

```js
//ticket channel is created with **"help: " + interaction.user.username** name


if (interaction.guild.channels.fetch('channel name'))
//working with only id

if (interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(c=>c.name==='channel name'))
//reacted nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

The discord.js channels cache is a `Discord.Collection` of values, meaning that it is a JS map with some extra quality of life methods added by Discord.js. Discord Collections are keyed using the snowflake id with the value being whatever object is being stored with that id (in this case the channel you want). This means that the method fetch on the collection of channels can always only be passed an ID as stated [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) in the docs. This would also mean that the `Map.get()` method you try to use in the second attempt will not return anything as the channel is not keyed by its name, its keyed by a snowflake id.

You can use a piece of code like this one I used in a discord moderation bot to find and return a channel by name if it exists in the cache.

```
/**
 * Get the log channel for the provided guild.
 * @param {Discord.Guild} guild The guild to get the log channel for.
*/
 #getLogChannel = (guild) => {
    const guildLogChannel = guild.channels.cache
    .find(channel => channel.name === 'guild-logs');

        if (!guildLogChannel) return false;
        return guildLogChannel;
 }
```

If the channel has not yet been cached you have no other option than to pass that channel into the interaction as an option, fetch the channel by its snowflake id, or fetch all channels for all guilds the bot is in inside your `client.on('ready', () => {})` handler. The last option is what I chose to do for the bot that the above code snippet is taken from.

Comment: nope. Didn't work

Comment: @Swipsy What did it return when you implemented it?